# Fortran Syntax Basics?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, gfortran, fortran95

So I am trying to get my Fortran 95 code to work just for basic function and program definitions. I get practically an error for every line saying "Unexpected" or "Unclassified". I wonder if it is my compiler (gfortran used in cygwin terminal) or if I am supposed to put something at the beginning of the file? Here it is if anyone can tell me anything.

```
    double precision :: pi = 3.14159265359

    PROGRAM Diffraction
            write (*,*) sinc(0)
            write (*,*) sinc(pi)
            write (*,*) 1_Slit(0, 1, 550E-9)
    end PROGRAM Diffraction

    function SINC(angle) result(sinc)
    double precision :: sinc
    double precision :: angle
    if angle == 0.0 then
            sinc == 1
    else
            sinc = (sin(angle)/angle)
    endif
    end function SINC

    function I(angle, d, wl) result(I)
            double precision :: I_0 = 0.01
            double precision :: angle, d, wl, I
            A = (d * pi)/wl
            B = SIN(angle)
            I = I_0 * (SINC(A*B)**f2)
    return
    end function I
```

The way I compile is:
gfortran Diffraction.f95

Comment: Nevermind. I spent a little bit of time looking at BNF for subprograms and such and eliminated every error.

Comment: Since you are on a windows platform, why not use Silverfrost.  It has a built in IDE (could even use the Visual Studio Express IDE)  which is quite good.  Just click on the error message and it will take you to the line of code.  Once you've got the syntax right, you could switch back to gfortran for faster speeds or you could just run it from silverfrost.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is a good idea to put all definitions in the main program or a module. So your "floating" definitions are a bit odd.

Your program should start with `PROGRAM [name]` followed by your used modules. In your case, there are no such modules. After this, it is good practice to write `IMPLICIT NONE`. This means, that no variables have a predefined type. Otherwise, every variable starting with `I` to `N` would be of type `INTEGER` and every other variable would be of type `REAL`.

The next part is the variable definition part, where your variables are defined. (The first line in your example.)

After this, the main part is following, where you execute your code.

The final part is the `CONTAINS` part, where your functions and subroutines are placed, which can use every variable, which is defined in the program (but this would be bad praxis...).

So your example (with some corrections) would look like:

```
PROGRAM Diffraction
IMPLICIT NONE

double precision :: pi = 3.14159265359d0

  write (*,*) sinc(0.d0)
  write (*,*) sinc(pi)
  write (*,*) one_slit(0.d0, 1.d0, 550.d-9)

CONTAINS

  function SINC(angle) result(snc)
    double precision :: snc
    double precision :: angle

    if (angle == 0.d0) then
      snc = 1.d0
    else
      snc = (sin(angle)/angle)
    endif
  end function SINC

  function one_slit(angle, d, wl) result(I)
    double precision :: I0 = 0.01d0, A, B
    double precision :: angle, d, wl, I, f2=2.d0

      A = (d * pi)/wl
      B = SIN(angle)
      I = I0 * (SINC(A*B)**f2)
  end function one_slit

end PROGRAM Diffraction
```

Comment: I would also add `parameter` to pi.